# ошибка при компиляции error: ';' expected

Tags: java

```
class Array1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double arr[] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 10.0};
        double getArr() {
            return (arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3] + arr[4] + arr[5] + arr[6] + arr[7] + arr[8] + arr[9]) / 10;
        }
        Array1 ar = new Array1();
        System.out.println("Среднее арифметическое массива: " + ar.getArr());
    }
}
```

error: ';' expected
        double getArr() {
                     ^ 1 error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Java нельзя объявлять функции внутри методов.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: @АлексейКрюков если проблема решена [отметьте ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers): слева должна быть серая галка, нажмите на нее.